# Magento: Override phtml inside /base/default/template

Tags: html, magento, php

I'm trying to override
*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/**form.phtml***.

I followed several guides without success:
I can only post one link since I don't have enough reputation to post more :(
http://www.magento.scommerce-mage.co.uk/override-phtml-or-layout-core-files-in-magento.html

In fact I'm even more confused now since they are all using different approaches. At the moment I'm trying to do it like in the last guide since this is the most up to date one(2014) without success so far.

So here is what I got:
*app/code/local/Namespace/MyModule/etc/**config.xml***

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <contactredirect>
                    <file>contactredirect.xml</file>
                </contactredirect>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/**contactredirect.xml***

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="contacts.form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>contactredirect/form.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

And finally the location of **my** form.phtml (the content probably doesn't matter):
*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contactredirect/**form.phtml***.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are certainly aware that you have to clean the layout cache every time you change a layout xml file and the config cache every time you change any xml config file, right?

Answer (score 0):

use "contactForm" in reference name ie code should be--

```
<reference name="contactForm">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>contactredirect/form.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it sadly didn't worked for me.
I need to do some more testing, hopefully this weekend but probably on monday. How do you know which reference name needs to be used?

Comment: In the layout file frontend/base/default/layout/contacts.xml you will see the block defined as <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>